# Why is the following true? (Cauchy sequence, Sobolev norm, weak derivative, $L^p$)

Tags: functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations

If $v_j$ is a Cauchy sequence w.r.t. the Sobolev norm , then the weak derivative of the sequence , i.e. $D^\alpha v_j$ is a Cauchy sequence wrt $L^p$ norm . 
Can anyone tell me why it's true?
Here norm is defined as $\displaystyle||u||=(\sum{||D^\alpha u||}^p _{L^p(\Omega)})^{1/p}$

Comment: You should probably add a few details on your definitions. What Sobolev space are you considering? Are you completing $C_{c}^\infty$ with respect to some norm (which is usually written as $H^{k,p}$ -- then there's actually something to prove here) or are you *defining* the Sobolev space as those $L^p$ functions whose weak derivatives exist and are $p$-integrable (usually written as $W^{k,p}$ and in that case there's not much to say except noting that the Sobolev norm dominates the $p$-norm of the weak derivatives)?

Comment: @t.b. exactly , i am dealing with the weak derivative one . What do you mean by saying that Sobolev norm dominates the p-norm ? can u explain a bit .

Comment: Well, write down the norm!

Comment: All I'm saying is that for $|\beta| \leq k$ we have  $\|D^\beta u\|_{L^p} \leq \left(\sum_{|\alpha| \leq k} \|D^\alpha u\|_{L^p}^p \right)^{1/p} = \|u\|_{W^{k,p}}$. From this you should see that if $(u_n)_{n=1}^\infty$ is a Cauchy sequence with respect to the Sobolev norm then $\|D^\beta u_n - D^\beta u_m\|_{L^p} \leq \|u_n - u_m\|_{W^{k,p}}$, so the sequence $(D^\beta u_n)_{n=1}^\infty$ is an $L^p$-Cauchy sequence.

Comment: @t.b. thank you . I am not able to edit the norm in the Latex properly . i am trying.

Comment: @Ananda: I imagine that's the norm you were trying to have? Please make sure my Texing was accurate.

Comment: @mixedmath thank you , i was trying to edit. I am not good at latex .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Sobolev norm is more or less the sum of the $L^p$ norms of the function and it's weak derivatives (up to an order depending on the Sobolev space). Thus $||Du||_p \leq ||u||_{W^{k,p}}$, and so a Sobolev-cauchy sequence of functions have cauchy weak derivatives (up to an order depending on the Sobolev space).

In particular, $||Du - Dv||_p \leq ||u - v||_{W^{k,p}}$ if $k \geq 1$, so if the larger is cauchy, then the smaller is cauchy too.